# Como faço para colocar uma coluna ao lado de outra bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-3

Bom é o seguinte, antes de mais peço desculpa pela pergunta ser um bocado burra, contudo eu sou novato em bootstrap.

O que pretendo fazer é um menu do lado esquerdo e outro menu do lado direito.

Como poderei fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Seu menu é no estilo do `navbar`? (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Seo menu for fixo tente realizar desta maneira: (atenção ao col-sm-X, o x deve fechar 12 ao somar os elementos)

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-3">Lista 1 aqui</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6">Conteúdo central</div>
 <div class="col-sm-3">Lista 2 aqui</div>
</div>
```